# Is it possible to stop twython streaming at certain point of time?

Tags: python, django, twython

**I have the codes for twython streaming and it is working.**

def read_cred(file):
 in_handle = open(file,'r')

```
cred = {}
for ln in in_handle:
    data = ln.strip('\r\n').split('=')
    if len(data) > 1:
        key = data[0].strip(' ').lower()
        value = data[1].strip(' ')
        cred[key] = value
    else:
        print "error in parsing credentials file"
return cred
```

cred = read_cred(sys.argv[1])

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
    act(data)

```
def on_error(self, status_code, data):
    print status_code, data
```

stream = MyStreamer(cred['consumer_key'], cred['consumer_secret'],
                    cred['access_token_key'], cred['access_token_secret'])

keywords = sys.argv[2]

stream.statuses.filter(track=keywords)

**However, I want to create a UI in django framework which consist of a 'start' and a 'stop' button. What should I do to stop the twython streaming when I clicked on the button 'stop' ? Can give me some simple examples pls?**

Answer (score 0):

As long as the stop button is bound to the rest of the app (I haven't used Django, so I can't provide a simple example) then calling sys.exit() should do the job.

Django might have some other method for terminating a process built into it or some specific examples in its documentation.  You should check that to confirm this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disconnect() function as described in the documentation of Twython - https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#twython.TwythonStreamer.disconnect

```
    def on_stop(self, status_code, data):
            self.disconnect()
    def on_start(keywords):
            stream = MyStreamer(cred['consumer_key'], cred['consumer_secret'],
                     cred['access_token_key'], cred['access_token_secret'])
            stream.statuses.filter(track=keywords)
```