# How to stop the twython streamer using pickle?

Tags: python, django, twython

**How to stop the twython streamer using pickle?**

```
def twitter_stop(request):
stream = request.session['stream']
pickle.dumps('models.pyc')
stream = pickle.load(pkl_file)

stream.disconnect()
return HttpResponse(request)
```

The above are my codes and I dun really know what should be put inside the pickle.dump

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I need help to disconnect my twython streamer in django.

Comment: With luck my answer to a similar question will help here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19083853/2801707